# Выводить блок <div> при нажатии на маркер (google maps)

Tags: google-maps

Помогите сделать вывод блока  с информацией при нажатии на маркер (google maps)

Пояснение ниже на скрине.
ТО есть при нажатии на маркер, должно открываться с углу карты блок с информацией о маркере, а стандартное пояснение маркера убрать.
Есть какой то способ сделать такое?

[image: вывод информации в блок на гугл карте]

Comment: Нужно см. лисенер onClick на маркере. То окно что по дефолту появляется называется infoWindow, его в коде можно отключить.